# Invite an external user from Person or Group column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver, external-users

I am creating a remote event receiver that makes sure a custom list with users (Person or Group column) are syncronized with some SharePoint groups. This is SharePoint Online.

I would like to also add external users to the list and have invitations sent to these users when I save the list item. At the moment I get an error telling me that external sharing must be turned on, which it is.

Anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly do you share the list? Can you post the steps? Does the sharing work with internal users? Is it root site?

There are several settings for external sharing. Make sure that:

1. When you go to SharePoint Admin Center>Settings>External sharing is on
   [image]
2. External sharing is on for the specific site collection:
   [image]
3. You perform it as an admin or "Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders." is on:
   [image]

Comment: I am using a custom list that has a Person or Group field. When the user adds an element to the list I have a remote event receiver that runs the ItemAdded event. In this event receiver I add the specified user to certain SharePoint groups. The problem I am facing is that the Person or Group field throws a validation error (JavaScript) if I try to specify the email address of an external user (in other words, a user that is not allready a user in my tenant).

Comment: Is it maybe possible to override the validation JavaScript that prevents me from adding the list item?